# mysql query returning double rows

Tags: mysql

I am using a standard apache2 LAMP configuration (mysql and php5), and UTF8 encoding.

I have set up four tables.

The first one is named `articles` and has 6 columns:

```
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(1000),
posted (TIMESTAMP)
author_id INT(11),
extract TEXT,
body TEXT
```

The second one is named `authors`

```
id INT(11) AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100),
img VARCHAR(100),
bio TEXT
```

The third one is named `categories`

```
id INT(2) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
cat_name VARCHAR(100)
```

And the fourth one is named `article_categories`

```
id INT(2) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
article_id INT(11),
category_id INT(2)
```

Now what I want is to write a mysql query that will find the title, author name and cat_name of an article. So far I've come up with this, and it returns 10 rows, basically all the categories I've set up. (I've set up one article with 2 categories, and 5 categories in the categories table).

This is my query:

```
SELECT articles.title, authors.name, categories.cat_name
FROM articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
WHERE title LIKE '%introduction%';
```

and my result:

```
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| title                  | name                  | cat_name     |
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | free         |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | free         |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | members-only |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | members-only |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | milestone    |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | milestone    |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | basic        |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | basic        |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | advanced     |
| An introduction to ptc | Yannick Šušteršič     | advanced     |
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to only display the article once, with all the corresponding categories name in a single row?

If not, how do I only get the relevant results? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've set up the query with the help of the anwsers suggested, and now I get 2 rows. If I use GROUP by on them, it will only display one row, with one cat_name, but I need both. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to sort trough my results using PDO/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to compare author and articles vs categories :

```
SELECT 
   articles.title, authors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cat_name)         
FROM 
   articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
WHERE 
   title LIKE '%introduction%' 
   AND articles.author_id = authors.id 
   AND articles.id = article_categories.article_id 
   AND article_categories.category_id = categories.id;
```

Updated, this is the final correct statement, authored by OP.

Comment: This now returns 2 rows, the same article twice, with different categories. Is there a way to now display the two categories in a single row, under the cat_name column?

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič, without knowing the data and unable to test, using `distinct` and exsplicitly refering to `article_categories` is what I can think of (updated answer)

Comment: the distinct actually does nothing here. I guess I can always set up 2 queries, and then work with that using PDO or jQuery. Thanks for the help

Comment: `SELECT articles.title, authors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cat_name)
FROM articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
WHERE title LIKE '%introduction%'
AND articles.author_id = authors.id
AND articles.id = article_categories.article_id
AND article_categories.category_id = categories.id;` Found what I was looking for, this is the final query. Update your anwser with it for future reference if you'd be so kind

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič, have just done that. Great, perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing what is called a `times` operation (cartesian product) instead of a `join` one, so that the result combines *all* the records, even if they are not related. What is missing in your query are the *join conditions* to restrict the result to only the records that are actually related, i.e.:

```
SELECT articles.title, authors.name, categories.cat_name
FROM articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
WHERE title LIKE '%introduction%' 
AND article_categories.article_id = articles.id
AND article_categories.category_id = categories.id
AND articles.author_id = authors.id
```